# Uploaded files duplicated in my project and AWS S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created Java program that can save files in AMAZON S3 storage - it works ok, but its saves files not only in S3 bucket, but also in my project directory.

Here is my code that saving files to S3. I suppose the reason why it saving in project directory also - is creation of file instance with specified path - `File file = new File(timestamp + ".jpg");` But how can I avoid that and still set needed file name without saving it to the project directory?

```
public void saveFileToStorage(String url, Long timestamp, Integer deviceId) {
    S3Repository repository = new S3Repository(bucketName);
    File file = new File(timestamp + ".jpg");
    try {
        URL link = new URL(url);
        Thread.sleep(1500);//wait until URL is ready for download
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(link, file);
        repository.uploadFile(timestamp.toString(), file, deviceId.toString()+"/");
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage() + " - check thread sleep time!");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Here is my upload method from repository:

```
public void uploadFile(String keyName, File file, String folder) {
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentLength(0);
    s3client.putObject(bucketName, folder, new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]), metadata);
    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, folder+keyName, file));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common to do something similar to what you've done.
I personally like the PutObjectRquest builder.

```
S3Client client = S3Client.builder().build();
PutObjectRequest request = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                        .bucket("bucketName").key("fileName").build();
client.putObject(request, RequestBody.fromFile(new File("filePath")));
```

To address your problem what about using `RequestBody.fromByteBuffer()` instead of `RequestBody.fromFile()`?

Here you can find an example:
https://stackabuse.com/aws-s3-with-java-uploading-files-creating-and-deleting-s3-buckets/